# Grouping to N number of Hashmaps into apache Spark JavaPairRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have to 2 HashMap,Where i grouped them into a Single HashMap

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();

    Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();

    map1.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
        List<String> val = result.get(key);
        if (val == null) {
            val = new ArrayList<String>();
            result.put(key, val);
        } else {
            val.addAll(map1.get(key));
            result.put(key, val);
        }
    });
    map2.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
        List<String> val = result.get(key);
        if (val == null) {
            val = new ArrayList<String>();
            result.put(key, val);
        } else {
            val.addAll(map2.get(key));
            result.put(key, val);
        }
    });
```

Now I want to do the same using apache spark and create a JavaPairRDD> .How to Implement it if I have N such Hashmaps and group them into a JavaPairRD> ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to transform each of your HashMap into a `JavaPairRDD`.
To do that, transform your HashMap into an array of `Tuple2` and use `JavaSparkContext.parrallelizePairs`.

Then, do a `union` of all your `JavaPairRDD`s, this will get you a single `RDD` with all the entries from all your maps.

Finally, you can use `groupByKey` to group the entries, but this will depend on what you want to do next, as `reduceByKey` might be better.